# Set selected row for large data array

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, paging

I have table with approx 100000 records, and display it in DataGridView using virtual mode. I implemented simple cache class that store 2 pages of data(each has 100 records) and then supply it to datagridview. But when I insert new record, I need to set it as a current position in datagridview. Is there any way how I can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the new record to the backing data store. Then use [FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx) to navigate to the newly added row, and CurrentCell (s. [CurrentRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) to set the current Row:

```
// first add record to backing store, then:
int rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowIndex;
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, rowIndex];
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's not exactly what i want :( I know how to set selected cell in GridView. But when i add new record to DB table, how i can get it position in GridView ? for example when i select records ordered by name, how i can get position of the record with id = 10 in returned data ?? that's what i want.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't asked that. Your question was: **"When I insert a new record, I need to set it as a current position in datagridview"**. Please edit your original question to exactly reflect what you are looking for.